# Build FFmpeg for All Android architecture correctly

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I built ffmpeg libraries for all android architecture. But some details are confusing my mind. First of all let me explain step by step how i built.

- I downloaded latest version of `libx264` from
  https://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html
- Created and run `build_all.sh` script (in x264 folder) for creating libs for (almost) all android platforms. Then i got `android` folder in x264 folder. e.g `android/arm` `android/arm64` `android/x86` `android/x86_64` in x264 folder.
- I download the `ffmpeg3.3.4` from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html
- I created 4 copies of `ffmpeg3.3.4` folder. Named them with android architectures names.
  Like `ffmpeg3.3.4-arm64` `ffmpeg3.3.4-arm` `ffmpeg3.3.4-x86` `ffmpeg3.3.4-x86_64`
- Created build_(architecture-name).sh for each platforms of android. Than move each one of `'named'.sh files` to the named ffmpeg folders according to their architecture names.
  E.g `build_android_x86.sh` => `ffmpeg3.3.4-x86`

`build_android_arm64.sh` example

```
#!/bin/bash
#Change NDK to your Android NDK location
NDK=$HOME/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
PLATFORM=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm64/
PREBUILT=$NDK/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

GENERAL="\
--enable-small \
--enable-cross-compile \
--extra-libs="-lgcc" \
--arch=aarch64 \
--cc=$PREBUILT/bin/aarch64-linux-android-gcc \
--cross-prefix=$PREBUILT/bin/aarch64-linux-android- \
--nm=$PREBUILT/bin/aarch64-linux-android-nm \
--extra-cflags="-I../x264/android/arm64/include" \
--extra-ldflags="-L../x264/android/arm64/lib" "

MODULES="\
--enable-gpl \
--enable-libx264"



function build_arm64
{
  ./configure \
  --logfile=conflog.txt \
  --target-os=linux \
  --prefix=./android/arm64-v8a \
  ${GENERAL} \
  --sysroot=$PLATFORM \
  --extra-cflags="" \
  --extra-ldflags="-lx264 -Wl,-rpath-link=$PLATFORM/usr/lib -L$PLATFORM/usr/lib -nostdlib -lc -lm -ldl -llog" \
  --enable-shared \
  --disable-static \
  --disable-doc \
  --enable-zlib \
  ${MODULES}

  make clean
  make
  make install
}

build_arm64


echo Android ARM64 builds finished
```

- Moved all `ffmpeg3.3.4-arm64` `ffmpeg3.3.4-arm` `ffmpeg3.3.4-x86` `ffmpeg3.3.4-x86_64` folders to the `NDK_PATH` (`C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle`)
- Put `x264` folder at same level of hierarchy with ffmpeg folders
  in (`C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle`)
- Run each of `build_android_x86.sh`, `build_android_x86_64.sh`.. scripts one by one in their own ffmpeg folder. Then i got `android` folders in ffmpeg folders. (created `android` folders have library folders)
  e.g `ffmpeg3.3.4-x86/android/x86/(bin,inlude,lib,share)`
- Created `Android.mk` files for all created `android` folders and moved each one of them to android/armName folder. e.g `Android.mk` => `ffmpeg3.3.4-x86/android/x86/`

  ```
  LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE:= libavcodec
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavcodec-57.so
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE:= libavformat
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavformat-57.so
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE:= libswscale
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libswscale-4.so
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE:= libavutil
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavutil-55.so
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE:= libavfilter
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libavfilter-6.so
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE:= libswresample
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= lib/libswresample-2.so
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE := postproc
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libpostproc-54.so
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE := avdevice
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := lib/libavdevice-57.so
  LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
  include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
  ```
- Create "arm named" folders e.g `x86` `x86_4` `arm64` `arm7` in jni folder of my project (`myproject/app/jni/x86`, `myproject/app/jni/x86_64`).
- Go to ndk path open named ffmpeg folders one by one and copy `ffmpeg.c` `ffmpeg_filter.c` `ffmpeg_opt.c` `cmdutils.c` files from ffmpeg folders to the "arm named" folders. e.g `ffmpeg.c` => `myproject/app/jni/x86`
- Created Android.mk file in my project.

  ```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
  #$(warning $(LOCAL_PATH))

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE    := videoEdit
  LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -ljnigraphics -lz -landroid
  LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Wdeprecated-declarations
  ANDROID_LIB := -landroid

  $(info $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI))

  ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)
      LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/ffmpeg-3.3.4-armeabi
      LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  videoEdit.c arm7/ffmpeg.c arm7/ffmpeg_filter.c arm7/ffmpeg_opt.c arm7/cmdutils.c
      LOCAL_CFLAGS += -lx264 -Wl,--no-merge-exidx-entries
  else

      ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
              LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/ffmpeg-3.3.4-arm64-v8a
              LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  videoEdit.c arm64/ffmpeg.c arm64/ffmpeg_filter.c arm64/ffmpeg_opt.c arm64/cmdutils.c
              LOCAL_CFLAGS += -funwind-tables -Wl,--no-merge-exidx-entries
      else

          ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
                 LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/ffmpeg3.3.4-x86_64
                 LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  videoEdit.c x86_64/ffmpeg.c x86_64/ffmpeg_filter.c x86_64/ffmpeg_opt.c x86_64/cmdutils.c
          else
                  LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:=/Users/MyName/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/ffmpeg3.3.4-x86
                  LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=  videoEdit.c x86/ffmpeg.c x86/ffmpeg_filter.c x86/ffmpeg_opt.c x86/cmdutils.c
          endif

      endif

  endif

  LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libavformat libavcodec libswscale libavutil libswresample libavfilter libavdevice libpostproc

  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi-v7a)

      $(call import-module,ffmpeg-3.3.4-armeabi/android/armeabi-v7a)

  else

      ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),arm64-v8a)
              $(call import-module,ffmpeg-3.3.4-arm64-v8a/android/arm64-v8a)
      else

          ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),x86_64)
                 $(call import-module,ffmpeg3.3.4-x86_64/android/x86_64)
          else
              $(call import-module,ffmpeg3.3.4-x86/android/i686-diasm)
          endif

      endif

  endif
  ```
- Created Application.mk file in my project.

  ```
  APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86_64, x86
  APP_PLATFORM := android-14
  ```
- Created videoEdit.c than run `ndk-build` build command.

**Built with no error**. I can run ffmpeg commands but it takes too much time i think. E.g when i try to run `hflip` it flips the video with 15 seconds.

**Code example :**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_com_name_app_library_VideoEditer_natives_VideoEditer_flipHorizontally
(JNIEnv *env, jclass someclass, jstring inputFile, jstring outFile) {

    int numberOfArgs = 14;

    char** arguments = calloc(numberOfArgs, sizeof(char*));
    const char *in, *out;

    in = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, inputFile, 0);
    out = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, outFile, 0);

    arguments[0] = "ffmpeg";
    arguments[1] = "-i";
    arguments[2] = in;
    arguments[3] = "-c:v";
    arguments[4] = "libx264";
    arguments[5] = "-preset";
    arguments[6] = "ultrafast";
    arguments[7] = "-threads";
    arguments[8] = "5";
    arguments[9] = "-c:a";
    arguments[10] = "copy";
    arguments[11] = "-vf";
    arguments[12] = "hflip";
    arguments[13] = out;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfArgs; i++) {
        log_message(arguments[i]);
    }
    log_message("Printed all");

    main(numberOfArgs, arguments);
    free(arguments);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, inputFile, in);
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, outFile, out);

    return 0;
}
```

FFmpeg Commands that runs on android, working very fast on emaulator but very slow on real device.

Also another thing to confusing my mind is output of `./configure` command.
When i open the (e.g) `ffmpeg-3.3.4-arm64-v8a` folder and run `./configure` command in terminal. Output says `ARCH   x86 (generic)`. For all platform output is the same `ARCH   x86 (generic)`.

**Output of `./configure` command in `ffmpeg-3.3.4-arm64-v8a` folder**

```
install prefix            /usr/local
source path               .
C compiler                gcc
C library                 glibc
ARCH                      x86 (generic)
big-endian                no
runtime cpu detection     yes
yasm                      yes
MMX enabled               yes
MMXEXT enabled            yes
3DNow! enabled            yes
3DNow! extended enabled   yes
SSE enabled               yes
SSSE3 enabled             yes
AESNI enabled             yes
AVX enabled               yes
XOP enabled               yes
FMA3 enabled              yes
FMA4 enabled              yes
i686 features enabled     yes
CMOV is fast              yes
EBX available             yes
EBP available             yes
debug symbols             yes
strip symbols             yes
optimize for size         no
optimizations             yes
static                    yes
shared                    no
postprocessing support    no
network support           yes
threading support         pthreads
safe bitstream reader     yes
texi2html enabled         no
perl enabled              yes
pod2man enabled           yes
makeinfo enabled          no
makeinfo supports HTML    no

External libraries:
iconv            xlib
```

**EDIT** all of these steps made on ubuntu then moved all folders to the windows. So dont be confuse about paths.

With all of these steps i want to ask is, is there anything wrong on my steps. Should i follow any other way or not ? Why the ffmpeg is running slower on real device. I am wondering one thing badly, how retrica, snapchat, instagram recording video as mirrored flipping ? Are they flipping after recorded (if they are how are they doing this in a second) or are they recording a video as flipped in run time ? I guess building ffmpeg for android is bit messy and making wrong things is very easy. If you look my steps, questions and give me an advice, i will be much appreciated.

Comment: I would look into the arch of the build files.  Also, are you missing `$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)` ?  IIRC, this is needed to turn on NEON optimized code.  See https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/master/TMessagesProj/jni/Android.mk

Comment: build of which file, sorry couldn't understand. do you mean build file of libx264 or build file of ffmpeg file ?

Comment: you are true it is missing. I will add the `$(call import-module,android/cpufeatures)` lets see how it effects.

Comment: @JamesPoag there is no change about performance of `hflip` video after adding `cpufeatures` (compiled with no error).

Comment: @fthopkins Sorry for asking foolish question. Why you are using libx264 and running all scripts inside this directory? Does compiling FFMPEG requires libx264?

Comment: @SagarTrehan It is not necessary, but it is like a steroid for ffmpeg. you can use libx264 commands with using libx264 for your ffmpeg. Also it helps you to edit high quality videos. (in 2018 almost every video has high quality)

Comment: @fthopkins Thanks for your valuable inputs. I asked this query because I am struggling to compile the FFMPEG3.4 with NDK16. Since you used libx264 here so I got confused. If you recently compiled FFMPEG3.4 with NDK16 then please share your valuable inputs on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48293404/error-in-building-ffmpeg-3-4-with-android-ndk-16-1/48310165#48310165 thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ARCH                      x86 (generic)
```

That's definitely wrong, it should be listing the specific architecture.

I think https://github.com/IljaKosynkin/FFmpeg-Development-Kit will help you, I was able to build all architectures correctly on first try with it. You are using command line ffmpeg so you will need to enable the program.

Comment: this answer is the best approach to my problem. thanks.

Comment: @fthopkins Please let us know what you were doing wrong and how you fix the issue. Did you follow the  https://github.com/IljaKosynkin/FFmpeg-Development-Kit to fix the issue? What exactly you updated to get the issue resolved?