# Error in building FFMPEG-3.4 with Android-NDK-16.1

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, android-ffmpeg

Trying to compile the FFMPEG-3.4 with Android-NDK-16.1.

Compiling the source on Mac.

Getting below Warnings/Errors:

1. WARNING: /Users/strehan/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
2. Error: In file included from libavdevice/avdevice.c:19:0:./libavutil/avassert.h:30:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
3. Error: /Users/strehan/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
4. Error: /libavutil/common.h:33:19: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory

Below is the `build_script.sh` using for build:

```
#!/bin/bash
NDK=/Users/strehan/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64
function build_one
{
./configure \
--prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-shared \
--disable-static \
--disable-doc \
--disable-ffmpeg \
--disable-ffplay \
--disable-ffprobe \
--disable-doc \
--disable-symver \
--enable-protocol=concat \
--enable-protocol=file \
--enable-muxer=mp4 \
--enable-demuxer=mpegts \
--cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
--target-os=linux \
--arch=arm \
--enable-cross-compile \
--sysroot=$SYSROOT \
--extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
--extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
$ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make -j3
make install
}
CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
build_one
```

Terminal output:

```
Enabled indevs:
lavfi

Enabled outdevs:

License: LGPL version 2.1 or later

WARNING: /Users/strehan/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-pkg-config not found, library detection may fail.
config.h is unchanged
libavutil/avconfig.h is unchanged
libavcodec/bsf_list.c is unchanged
libavformat/protocol_list.c is unchanged
ffbuild/config.sh is unchanged
GEN libavutil/libavutil.version
GEN libswscale/libswscale.version
GEN libswresample/libswresample.version
GEN libavcodec/libavcodec.version
GEN libavformat/libavformat.version
GEN libavfilter/libavfilter.version
GEN libavdevice/libavdevice.version
CC  libavdevice/alldevices.o
CC  libavdevice/avdevice.o
CC  libavdevice/lavfi.o
In file included from libavdevice/avdevice.c:19:0:
./libavutil/avassert.h:30:20: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdlib.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [libavdevice/avdevice.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ./libavutil/avutil.h:296:0,
                 from ./libavutil/log.h:25,
                 from libavdevice/avdevice.h:48,
                 from libavdevice/alldevices.c:23:
./libavutil/common.h:33:19: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory
 #include <errno.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from ./libavutil/avstring.h:25:0,
                 from ./libavutil/bprint.h:27,
                 from libavdevice/lavfi.c:30:
/Users/strehan/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/include/stdint.h:9:26: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
 # include_next <stdint.h>
                          ^
make: *** [libavdevice/alldevices.o] Error 1
compilation terminated.
make: *** [libavdevice/lavfi.o] Error 1
INSTALL doc/examples/avio_dir_cmd.c
INSTALL doc/examples/avio_reading.c
INSTALL doc/examples/decode_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/decode_video.c
INSTALL doc/examples/demuxing_decoding.c
INSTALL doc/examples/encode_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/encode_video.c
INSTALL doc/examples/extract_mvs.c
INSTALL doc/examples/filter_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/filtering_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/filtering_video.c
INSTALL doc/examples/http_multiclient.c
INSTALL doc/examples/hw_decode.c
INSTALL doc/examples/metadata.c
INSTALL doc/examples/muxing.c
INSTALL doc/examples/qsvdec.c
INSTALL doc/examples/remuxing.c
INSTALL doc/examples/resampling_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/scaling_video.c
INSTALL doc/examples/transcode_aac.c
INSTALL doc/examples/transcoding.c
INSTALL doc/examples/vaapi_encode.c
INSTALL doc/examples/README
INSTALL doc/examples/Makefile
INSTALL doc/examples/avio_dir_cmd.c
INSTALL doc/examples/avio_reading.c
INSTALL doc/examples/decode_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/decode_video.c
INSTALL doc/examples/demuxing_decoding.c
INSTALL doc/examples/encode_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/encode_video.c
INSTALL doc/examples/extract_mvs.c
INSTALL doc/examples/filter_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/filtering_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/filtering_video.c
INSTALL doc/examples/http_multiclient.c
INSTALL doc/examples/hw_decode.c
INSTALL doc/examples/metadata.c
INSTALL doc/examples/muxing.c
INSTALL doc/examples/qsvdec.c
INSTALL doc/examples/remuxing.c
INSTALL doc/examples/resampling_audio.c
INSTALL doc/examples/scaling_video.c
INSTALL doc/examples/transcode_aac.c
INSTALL doc/examples/transcoding.c
INSTALL doc/examples/vaapi_encode.c
INSTALL doc/examples/README
INSTALL doc/examples/Makefile
CC  libavdevice/alldevices.o
In file included from ./libavutil/avutil.h:296:0,
                 from ./libavutil/log.h:25,
                 from libavdevice/avdevice.h:48,
                 from libavdevice/alldevices.c:23:
./libavutil/common.h:33:19: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory
 #include <errno.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [libavdevice/alldevices.o] Error 1
```

Please help to fix these errors. Due to these errors/warnings compilation is getting terminated.

**Note:**
Android directory is getting created even after these errors. But I think library is not compiled properly due to above errors.

Let me know if anything else needed. Please help.

Comment: Same problem, and can't find the solution, then just move to NDK14

Comment: Same problem, lol. Tried solving this for 2 weeks, anyone has any solution till now?

Answer (score 1):

Your build script is out of date and not compatible with modern NDKs (it doesn't follow https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/UnifiedHeaders.md#supporting-unified-headers-in-your-build-system).

I'd recommend saving yourself some trouble and using a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) to handle the organizational bits for you.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. If possible can you please help compiling FFMPEG3.4 for NDK16 with standalone toolchain? I am trying to use stanalone toolchain but facing multiple issue.

Comment: I know this isn't a valid answer, but can you try using NDK12?
I have faced issues building FFMPEG using NDK16 too.